# Getting two consecutive elements from a list every ten elements

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list `A` and I want to get elements 1, 2, 11, 12, 21, 22, etc. as a list.

For example, if `A = range(100)`, then I want `[0, 1, 10, 11, 20, 21, ..., 90, 91]`

Right now I have `[num for elem in [[A[i], A[i+1]] for i in range(0, len(A)-1, 10)] for num in elem]`

Is there a more concise or more efficient way to implement this?

Comment: It is not clear what your desired output is.

Comment: Are your elements just numbers? Or could they be other objects/types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[elem for i, elem in enumerate(A) if i %10 in (0, 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the pairs (this will not include 100 if 101 is not in range) use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) with [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) (consider using [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) and [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) for bigger values of `N`):

```
itertools.chain(*zip(range(0, N, 10), range(1, N, 10)))
```

Or avoiding the unpacking using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(range(0, N, 10), range(1, N, 10)))
```

To view the content:

```
>>> N = 100
>>> list(itertools.chain(*zip(range(0, N, 10), range(1, N, 10))))
[0, 1, 10, 11, 20, 21, 30, 31, 40, 41, 50, 51, 60, 61, 70, 71, 80, 81, 90, 91]
```

Comment: It should be noted here that you can do this without unpacking by using `itertools.chain.from_iterable` instead. +1, nonetheless.

Comment: Mention `izip` for Python 2 users.

Answer (score 3):

Use the modulus operator with `enumerate()` to filter by the index.

```
[elem for idx,elem in enumerate(A) if idx%10 in (0,1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
[A[i] for i in xrange(0, len(A)) if i%10 in (0, 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
[i for t in zip(A[::10],A[1::10]) for i in t]
```

*Logic* - Loop over two elements in the list by skipping 10 at once but starting one of them from 1 and the other from 0

Using the same logic, you can try [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) (For Py2 users)

```
from itertools import izip
[i for t in izip(A[::10],A[1::10]) for i in t]
```

Timing -

- `zip`

  ```
  $ python -m timeit -s "A = range(100)" "[i for t in zip(A[::10],A[1::10]) for i in t]"
  100000 loops, best of 3: 1.98 usec per loop
  ```
- `izip`

  ```
  $ python -m timeit -s "A = range(100);from itertools import izip" "[i for t in izip(A[::10],A[1::10]) for i in t]"
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.79 usec per loop
  ```

Comparing other answers

```
$ python -m timeit -s "A = range(100)" "[elem for idx,elem in enumerate(A) if idx%10 in (0,1)]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.39 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "A = range(100)" "[A[i] for i in xrange(0, len(A)) if i%10 in (0, 1)]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.92 usec per loop
```

`izip` is very fast here!

Answer (score 1):

Since Bhargav Rao took the [obvious](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) choice of zipping slices, here's a fairly simple coroutine to do this, since `filter` just needs two `True`'s and eight `False`'s to get this right:

```
import itertools # only needed for Python 2
def first_two_of_ten():
    x2, x8 = xrange(2), xrange(8) # use range in Python 3
    yield # gotta queue up a coroutine to send to it
    while True:
        for i in x2:
            yield True
        for i in x8:
            yield False
```

and usage:

```
ftot = first_two_of_ten()
next(ftot) # gotta queue the coroutine up
```

and the actual usage by [`itertools.ifilter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter)

```
>>> list(itertools.ifilter(ftot.send, xrange(50)))
[0, 1, 10, 11, 20, 21, 30, 31, 40, 41]
```

Again, substitute `range` for `xrange` in Python 3, and just use the builtin `filter` for Python 3 as well.